# Elasticsearch match_phrase query inside multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple multi_match query like this:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "RNA sequencing"
        }
    }
}
```

This works well as intended, however I'd like to make my query a match phrase query so it returns "RNA sequencing" as a phrase and not "RNA" and "sequencing" separately. I tried doing this

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "RNA sequencing", "type": "phrase"
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "match_phrase": {"query": "RNA sequencing"}
        }
    }
}
```

but they both result parsing errors. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title":"sequencing"
}
{
    "title":"RNA sequencing"
}
{
    "title":"RNA"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "RNA sequencing",
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65314008",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.9808291,
        "_source": {
          "title": "RNA sequencing"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Brian Guan did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @Brian Guan it's been a long time now. I hope you are doing well  If my answer, helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer 